# Hide a textview in custom listview's adapter, for a loop

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a custom list view with with a custom row containing date, duty and name. If the date comes twice, the second date should be hidden. How can i hide the date for the particular position from adapter.

My program looks like this

This is custom row.

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_duty_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_duty_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_duty_member_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This is my adapter

```
TextView name, duty, date_time;

viewHolder.duty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_duty_name);

viewHolder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_duty_member_name);

viewHolder.date_time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_duty_date);

for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++){
            if (j == 0){

            }else {
                String current_date = data.get(j).getDateTime());
                String previous_previous = data(j-1).getDateTime());
                if (current_date.equals(previous_date)) {
                    viewHolder.date_time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
```

If I do this all the date gets hidden. I want to hide when two dates are equal.

Comment: Do you want to hide the date or the whole list item?

Comment: Only the date, that to when two dates are sam

Comment: Please remove the for loop and replace j with "position" from your getView() arguments. You are now setting visibility of all items according to date of the last 2 items of the list (data).

Comment: @I_A_Mok thanks done the same thing yesterday and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Add else part

```
for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++){
        if (j == 0){

        }else {
            String current_date = data.get(j).getDateTime());
            String previous_previous = data(j-1).getDateTime());
            if (current_date.equals(previous_date)) {
                viewHolder.date_time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                viewHolder.date_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had now added the else part but the date is visible now. I just need to hide the date of the position j. Can you help me?

Comment: If the condition is true date is invisible for this position and if condition is false date is visible for a particular position..

Comment: can you post the whole adapter class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in getview() method,

```
if(position>0)
      {
           String current_date = data.get(position).getDateTime());
                String previous_previous = data(position-1).getDateTime());
                if (current_date.equals(previous_date)) {
                    viewHolder.date_time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else  {
                     viewHolder.date_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++){
            if (j == 0){

            }else {
                String current_date = data.get(j).getDateTime());
                String previous_previous = data(j-1).getDateTime());
                if (current_date.equals(previous_date)) {
                    viewHolder.date_time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {                        
                   viewHolder.date_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Edit**

```
if (current_date.equals(previous_date)) {
                        viewHolder.date_time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else
                    {                        
                       viewHolder.date_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
```

Comment: I had now added the else part but the date is visible now. I just need to hide the date of the position **j**. Can you help me?

Comment: @BalasubramaniG please add screen shot to achive your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
I will suggest check First which layout you want to show, then inflate the layout every time after checking inside "getView" function of Adapter.

View v = convertView;
  int type = getItemViewType(position);
  if (v == null) {
    // Inflate the layout according to the view type
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) `enter code here`ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   if (type == 0) {
     // Inflate the layout with image
     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_with_date, parent, false);
  }
  else {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_with_out_date, parent, false);
  }
 }
```